# Schemacrawler in OSGi bundle

Tags: schemacrawler

I'm really new to Schemacrawler and I need a little help. I want to use Schemacrawler as OSGi bundle in my project. However I'm not sure how to do it. In the [Readme](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/readme.html), it says that "The SchemaCrawler jar file is bundled as an OSGi bundle". But there are a lot of schemacrawlers jars in the [Maven repo](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Aus.fatehi%20schemacrawler). Which one should I use?

Another question is, I tried to import only the schemacrawler jar into my project, and did a little test with sqlite. It did work nicely, however I'm wondering do I need to include all other the database specific jars (e.g schemacrawler-sqlite) as well? What are they for actually? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eli,

Here is a resource on OSGi in Java: [OSGi Modularity - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGi/article.html). You should use the [latest version of the main SchemaCrawler jar](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22us.fatehi%22%20AND%20a%3A%22schemacrawler%22). If you are using SQLite, you should also use the corrsponding version of [SchemaCrawler for SQlite jar](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22us.fatehi%22%20AND%20a%3A%22schemacrawler-sqlite%22). The SchemaCrawler for SQlite jar provides additional functionality specifically for SQLite.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://www.SchemaCrawler.com)